# How do you make a unique map key in Python?

Tags: python

I want to make a map containing various attributes of a single item and share it across several modules.  The most obvious answer is to use a string, but since the map will be used across several modules, I don't want maintainers to have to know about all existing attributes.  For example, if two modules want something associated with "color", they shouldn't clobber each other by accidentally picking the same name.

A few ideas I've thought of which don't work:

1) Strings, integer keys: As said above, this isn't easily extensible.

2) Create of a particular class, use id():  I thought it would work to make a Key() class, for example, but this doesn't work in the case of modules imported from two different places.  For example, you might want to make the "color" attribute described above as follows:

```
color = Key()
```

This doesn't work if you do

# module named foo

```
bar = Key()
import foo
id(foo.bar) == id(bar)
```

3) Look at the stack trace to see where the Key was created and use that as part of the identifier.  Definitely wouldn't want to use line number, as this would be too brittle.  Using module and name of item fails in the case of the main module, though.  For example:

in foo.py:

```
key = Key() # will be named foo.py-key
```

elsewhere, in bar.py:

```
import foo

foo.key   # will be named /Users/person/foo.py-key
```

Thanks!  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: **don't** import the same module under two different names.  you deserve whatever horrible things happen if you do.

Comment: Are python imports supposed to always be a directed graph?  If not, then in the case of circular imports, one can import the same module twice, once as "\_\_main\_\_" and once as "foo.py".  How would one avoid that?  Also, what if people follow different conventions, one importing as "import foo.bar" and the other as "import foo.bar as bar"?  Most importantly, what solution are you implying by saying modules should only be important under one name?  Thanks!

Comment: the only way your solution 2 is a problem is if the module is actually loaded twice, which only happens if it appears twice in your module hierarchy, which should not happen.  **don't** run part of your module hierarchy directly; if `foo.py` is supposed to be a module called `foo`, run it as `python -m foo` (which will put it in the right place), not `python foo.py`.  local aliasing doesn't matter; `import foo.bar` and `import foo.bar as bar` both load a module with the name `foo.bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string, but prefix it with the current module name. Then you won't get any collisions.

```
key = __name__ + '.color'
```

Comment: A good idea, but the current module name isn't \_\_name\_\_ - that could easily be "\_\_main\_\_" instead.

Perhaps looking at the current stack trace would give me the module name, but that fails if foo.py shows up in two separate directories.  Still, that's closer than what I have now.